# How to limit rows in select using parameter

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to set limit for selected rows using parameter but obviously I can't write something like:

```
select top @count * from tbl
```

Also, I'm not very happy about turning select into string like:

```
exec('select top ' + casttovarchar(@count) + ' * from tbl')
```

**Question**: Is it posible and how to parametrize `select top`?

Comment: Adding `Order By` to your query will make the result more consistent

Comment: @Prdp this is not whole qry, whole qry is very large

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible using brackets:

```
select top (@count) * from tbl
```